# Disabling auto-login after it was once enabled during build

Tags: ubuntu, gui, raspi-config, login

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS ( Mate, built with ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img )
When I initially built this, I enabled the auto-login when going through all the initial questions.  But now, after it is built and doing what I want, I wish to disable the GUI and have it boot to the CLI.  I went through the usual raspi-config and changed the Boot Options + Desktop/CLI, and selected CLI.  But when I boot, it does go to CLI, but networking doesn't seem to be working unless I actually log into the CLI as the user I initially created.  I tried waiting several minutes, but the networking will never come up and I can not connect to the pi remotely unless I log into the CLI console first.  So, the only thing I can think of is there is some setting confused due to the pi initially being setup with auto-login.  So, I re-enabled the GUI login and rebooted.  Upon doing so, networking works after boot as it did before.  I'm now trying to see if I can disable the auto-login at the GUI.  Then, I'll try to do the raspi-config again and change it to CLI login.   But I can't find anywhere to disable the user from auto-login.   Where is that setting?  Does it exist?  Or did I just stumble upon a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using some paragraphs - this is unreadable

Comment: You wrote: "*I wish to disable the GUI and have it boot to the CLI.*" and "*But when I boot, it does go to CLI*". What's the problem here? I don't understand. What is this issue with disabled networking? Does it enable automagically when you just login on the CLI?

Comment: Ingo, continue reading that sentence.   "It does go to the CLI, but networking doesn't seem to be working unless I actually log into the CLI".    That's the problem.  I have to enter the user ID and password at that CLI before the pi comes up on the network.

Comment: If I reading this correctly, you wish to have the GUI load but not to log in automatically?